# How to get a value from a complicated dictionary?

Tags: swift

An API returns this response below but I don't know how to parse it.

Response JSON

```
[
 "results": [
    [
      "address": "mgG2W14th6TXYWXNDrZ24shsJ2wYhJm2b3",
      "total": [
        "balance": 0,
        "received": 0,
        "sent": 0
      ],
      "confirmed": [
        "balance": 0,
        "received": 0,
        "sent": 0
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Swift Code

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.chain!.getAddress(address!) { dictionary, error in
    NSLog("%@", dictionary)
}
```

Dictionary Object

```
(lldb) po dictionary
[results: (
        {
        address = mgG2W14th6TXYWXNDrZ24shsJ2wYhJm2b3;
        confirmed =         {
            balance = 0;
            received = 0;
            sent = 0;
        };
        total =         {
            balance = 0;
            received = 0;
            sent = 0;
        };
    }
)]
```

I tried it many times... Can you share how to fix it please..

```
(lldb) po dictionary["results"]![0]
{
    address = mgG2W14th6TXYWXNDrZ24shsJ2wYhJm2b3;
    confirmed =     {
        balance = 0;
        received = 0;
        sent = 0;
    };
    total =     {
        balance = 0;
        received = 0;
        sent = 0;
    };
}

po dictionary["results"]![0]!["address"]
error: <EXPR>:1:28: error: cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject' with an index of type 'String'
dictionary["results"]![0]!["address"]
```

I got "Could not find member 'subscript'" at "let address = ..." line.

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.chain!.getAddress(address!) { dictionary, error in
        NSLog("%@", dictionary)

        let address = dictionary["results"]![0]["address"]!
        print("address: \(address)")
    }
```

Comment: Accessing container contents is not parsing. JSON is text and the process of converting it to a collection object is the parsing.

Comment: Since my answer does not answer the question I am deleting it.

Comment: are you sing Swift 1.2 or are you developing with Swift 2? I am asking cause it is a bit neater in Swift 2 to parse it using 'guard' statements

Comment: Thanks for response. Swift version is 1.2.

Comment: Here is what i *think*: The deserialization from the JSON string is creating a slightly different dictionary object internally than crewatint one in Swift code. Perhaps an `NSDictionay` vs a `Dictionary`.

Comment: The API library is written in objective-c. I'm using a bridge file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let myDictionary = dictionary as? [String:AnyObject] {
if let results = myDictionary["results"] as? [AnyObject] {
    if let firstItem = results[0] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let address = firstItem["address"] as? String {
            print(address)
        }
        if let total = firstItem["total"] as? [String:Int] {
            if let balance = total["balance"] {
                print(balance)
            }
            if let received = total["received"] {
                print(received)
            }
            if let sent = total["sent"] {
                print(sent)
            }
        }
        if let confirmed = firstItem["confirmed"] as? [String:Int] {
            if let balance = confirmed["balance"] {
                print(balance)
            }
            if let received = confirmed["received"] {
                print(received)
            }
            if let sent = confirmed["sent"] {
                print(sent)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In order to simplify things you can create a class which will be managing such parsing if the data returned always has the same format.

Comment: @zono you are welcome. In Swift 2 this can be done much more easily with guard keywords. So, if you are planning to release in a couple of weeks time I strongly encourage you to migrate ;)

Comment: OK I will switch to Swift2.